# fread() return 0 while feof(filepointer) return 0

Tags: c

I have tried to read serveral files into buffer.
Most of them succeed,but one of them didn't.
This always happen when reached (end of file)-1.

Part of the code:

```
char buf[1024];
long validbyte,filesize=0;
while(!feof(fp)){
    validbyte=fread(buf,sizeof(char),sizeof(buf),fp);
    filesize++;
}
printf("File size is : %ld",filesize);
printf("validbyte is %ld\n",validbyte);
```

The actually file size is 1044480 kb,but "filesize" is always display 1044481,and fread() return 0 at (end of file)-1 .
[The result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNBC4.png)

That file is ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso ,which download at ubuntu offical website.

So what happened when fread() return 0 and not reach the end of the file?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.

Comment: PS: `fread` returns `size_t` not long

Comment: @EdHeal actually, it's a duplicate

Comment: @FelixPalmen - Did not read the question yet - just glimpsed at the code